# Escape sequence discrepancy

Tags: c, escaping, sequence

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
          int i=0;
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\1');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\2');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\3');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\4');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\5');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\6');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\7');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\8');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\9');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\10');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\11');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\12');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\13');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\14');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\15');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\16');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\17');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\18');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\19');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\20');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\21');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\22');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\23');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\24');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\25');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\26');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\27');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\28');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\29');
          printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,'\30');
          return 0;
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
1:   1
2:   2
3:   3
4:   4
5:   5
6:   6
7:   7
8:  56    
9:  57
10:   8
11:   9
12:  10
13:  11
14:  12
15:  13
16:  14
17:  15
18: 312
19: 313
20:  16
21:  17
22:  18
23:  19
24:  20
25:  21
26:  22
27:  23
28: 568
29: 569
30:  24
```

Isn't '\1' equivalent to the character whose ASCII value is 1?
In the output, why are the numbers at 8,9,18,19,28,29... not in order?
http://codepad.org/I1N6A71j

Comment: The compiler is your friend. Always enable all warnings. Mine says, "warning: unknown escape sequence: '\8' [enabled by default]", "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]".

Comment: If I remember it right, \n is equivalent to the octal ASCII value of n. Therefore \8 is illegal.

Comment: [link]http://codepad.org/I1N6A71j

Comment: @Dmitri: It has nothing to do with `\n`. It has to do with the fact that 8 is not a valid octal digit.

Comment: @R.. Here n stands for an arbitrary integer number :-)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: printf("%c",'\1012'); is working in my compiler. It has more than three octal digits.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood your comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 2.14.3:

> The escape `\ooo` consists of the backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. The escape `\xhhh` consists of the backslash followed by `x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. There is no limit to the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence. A sequence of octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by the first character that is not an octal digit or a hexadecimal digit, respectively.

Since `\8` and `\18` are not valid sequences of octals, the meaning of those literals depends on your platform:

> Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 7 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics.

Comment: are those single quotes allowed in printf statement never seen them can you provide me link where i can read about it how is it possible

Answer (score 2):

Escape sequences are supposed to be in octal, thus \8 and \9 are not allowed and result in unspecified behavior.
The result depends on the compiler you are using; in this case, it is ignoring the escape and handling '8' and '9' as plain ascii-char.

To get the proper (ascii-char) result, you should use \x8 and \x9.

Answer (score 1):

This is the compiler output (MinGW):

```
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:12:33: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\8'
a.c:13:33: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\9'
a.c:22:33: warning: multi-character character constant
a.c:23:33: warning: multi-character character constant
a.c:32:33: warning: multi-character character constant
a.c:33:33: warning: multi-character character constant
```

Some of these escape sequences are invalid in c. Escape sequences are in octal in C. You could also easily detect this if you had a decent editor. My ViM marks `\8` and `\9` in red because they are invalid.

Comment: There is no need/no use for a cast. Character literals have type `int`. And even **if** they had type `char` (which they don't), all variadic arguments are subject to default promotions and thus get promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The number after `\` is treated as *octal*. I've no idea why the `\8`, `\9`, `\19`, etc. sequences are so odd, though. Since they're not valid octal numbers, the compiler is probably free to do anything with them.

Escape sequences can be specified in hex, if you'd prefer, as `\x1`, `\x2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use hh before format d modificator needed!!! So you use d format it's assumes int32 value, but you use only char - 8 bit value!!! It's memory wrong accsss!!! Only c99 available or c++11.
Or you need some intermediate value like that:

```
short val = '\1'; //for C 89
  printf("%d:%4hd\n",++i, val);
val =  '\2';
  printf("%d:%4d\n",++i,val);
......
or 
  printf("%d:%4hhd\n",++i,'\1'); //for c99
```

Either don't work correctly!!!